# Converting Generating function to discrete numeric function.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, partial-fractions

I am having trouble solving this problem.
$$ A(z) = \frac{5+2z}{1-4z^2} $$
I know how to solve
$$ A(z) =\frac{1}{5-6z+z^2} $$

$$ A(z) = \frac{1}{(z-1)*(z-5)}= \frac{A}{z-1}+\frac{B}{z-5}$$
$$A = \frac{-1}{4}\quad B=\frac{1}{4}$$
$$A(z)=\frac{-1}{4*(z-1)}+\frac{1}{4*(z-5)}$$
$$ A(z)=\frac{1}{4*(1-z)}-\frac{1}{20*(1-z/5)}$$
$$ A(z) =\frac{1}{4}*\sum_{r=0}^\infty(z^r)-\frac{1}{20}*\sum_{r=0}^\infty((\frac{z}{5})^r)                           $$
$$ A(z)= \frac{1}{4} \left[\sum_{r=0}^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{5^{r+1}}\right){z^r}\right] $$
Since $$A(z)=\sum_{r=0}^\infty({a_r}*{z^r}) $$

therefore
$$ a_r= \frac{1}{4}\sum_{r=0}^\infty({1-\frac{1}{5^{r+1}}})$$

I need answer in similar fashion

Comment: Tell me whether this is the correct method or not too, please.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note that $1-4z^2=(1-2z)(1+2z)$.

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica evaluates `Apart[(5+2z)/(1-4z^2)]//InputForm` to `-3/(-1 + 2*z) + 2/(1 + 2*z)`.

Comment: Can you solve $\frac5{1-4z^2}$?